# Couldn't make div width as responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, onsen-ui

Here is my code.

I have used vertical tab using jquery and onsenui.

In Firefox: Use CTRL+SHIFT+M to view in mobile/tablet mode.

Right now I am using this for tablet which is more than 600px

index.html

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      ons.bootstrap();
      $('#tabs').tabs().addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
    });
```

```css
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical {
  padding: 0;
  width: 42em;
  margin-left: 6%;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-widget-header {
  border: none;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  border: none;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.6em 1em;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid white;
  border-left: 4px solid #7fcc28;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 7px;
}
#a,
#b,
#c {
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/css/onsen-css-components.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://onsen.io/OnsenUI/build/js/onsenui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <ons-navigator>
    <ons-page>
      <div style="min-height: 150px;"></div>
      <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" style="line-height: 500px; padding: 0 14px; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
        <ons-row>
          <ons-col>
            <div id="tabs" style="background-color: #F2F2F2; width:100%;">

              <ul>
                <li style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px #888888;">
                  <a href="#a" style="font-style: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: #666666;">Vertical Tab 1</a>
                </li>
                <li style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px #888888;">
                  <a href="#b" style="font-style: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: #666666;">Vertical Tab 2</a>
                </li>
                <li style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px #888888;">
                  <a href="#c" style="font-style: Arial; font-size: 14px; color:#666666;">Vertical Tab 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <div id="a" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px #888888; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                something goes here 1
              </div>


              <div id="b" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px #888888; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                something goes here 2
              </div>


              <div id="c" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px #888888; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                something goes here 3
              </div>
            </div>
          </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-navigator>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the output I got

[image]

But when I expand the screen, I couldn't make the width responsive like above image.
I am getting some extra spaces in the right side like below.

[image]

Could somebody help?

Comment: Can't answer the question, sorry. But thanks for learning me that shortcut and that feature of firefox. Didn't knew that :-)

Comment: Use % widths instead of px. something like **#a,#b,#c{width:60%;}** would get you on your way. You'd then need to use **media queries** for when you screen gets smaller.

Comment: I always use % only bro. But in this case, I tried width. but couldn't make it. I used media query only. When the user auto rotates the screen, i.e landscape, in that I am facing this width issue.

Comment: The vertical list and the 2nd column need to be inline-blocks, within a shared container. Set the width of this to 100%. Set the width of the vertical list to whatever you want. And then set the 2nd column to the width of 100% minus the width of the vertical list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `width:50%` to `width: calc(100% - 6% - 300px);` in `.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel`

Then change `width:10em` to e.g. `width:180px` for `.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav`

By using calc- you can set the width of the element to accommodate for changes to the given widths of the sidebar etc. At present, it is simply fixed to `50%`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqmyfL5e/)

Comment: Worked! Why I need to change width for ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav ?

Comment: And could you please explain how this works calc(100% - 6% - 300px)

Comment: @UIDesigner - calc = calculate, takes the while available width (100%), subtracts the left hand margin (you have set to 6%) then subtracts a fixed amount to provide a right hand margin